# concatenate strings sequentially in python

Tags: python, list, concatenation

I need to concatenate strings in a list sequentially to join the two parts of words that were separated by line breaks. Can someone help me?

```
list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Required output:

```
"ab"
"cd"
```

Comment: Are the variables string with line break in you want to remove?

Comment: Is the List Fix contains element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a method which groups for you the elements in the list:

```
def group_by(iterable, n = 2):
  if len(iterable)%n != 0: raise Exception("Error: uneven grouping")
  # if n < 2: n = 1
  i, size = 0, len(iterable)
  while i < size-n+1:
    yield iterable[i:i+n]
    i += n
```

So for example if your list is:

```
words = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
group_by(words, 2) #=> [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
```

Or you can group by 3:

```
words = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
cons = group_by(words, 3) #=> [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

Then you can use in this way:

```
res = [ "".join(pair) for pair in group_by(words, 2) ] # maybe you want to add "\n" to the joined string
#=> ['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
```

---

The method throws an error if number of elements can not be evenly grouped:

```
words = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
cons = group_by(words, 2) #=> Exception: Error: uneven grouping
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to join pairs of consecutive items:

```
>>> lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> list(map(''.join, zip(*([iter(lst)]*2))))
['ab', 'cd']
```

Here, `zip(*([iter(lst)]*2))` is a common recipe for pairs of elements by `zip`ing two instances of the same iterator on the list, but there are many other ways to do the same.

(Note: Renamed `list` to `lst` for not shadowing the builtin type)

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in range(0, len(l), 2):
    ''.join(l[i:i + 2])
```

Comment: Thank you again! Is this another method?

Comment: It does the job as all the rest. I like it because it is not tricky but just a normal loop.

Answer (score 2):

Using a shared iterator,

```
>>> [x + next(itr) for itr in [iter(lst)] for x in itr]
['ab', 'cd']
```

In the forthcoming Python 3.8 (ETA fall 2019), that can be more succinctly written (I believe) as

```
[x + next(itr) for x in (itr:=iter(lst))]
```

Comment: Nice. Only approach so far that will raise an exception if the list has an odd length instead of just omitting the last item, but a bit nasty to extend to more than two elements.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: BTW, do you know why they don't use e.g. `for x in (iter(lst) as itr)`, reusing `as` from `import`, `with` and `except` instead of introducing new `:=`?

Comment: The decision to support some form of assignment expression was made quickly. The debate over the exact syntax to use dragged on... and on... and on.  `as` was eventually rejected to avoid adding another set of slightly different semantics on top of what existing uses of `as` already defined. See [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#rejected-alternative-proposals) for all the gory details.

Answer (score 1):

Given a list,

```
L=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

(note, not hijacking the keyword `list` for a variable name)

you can walk through this in steps of two:

```
for i in range(0,len(L)-1,2):
  print(L[i]+L[i+1])
```

Use `rstrip` to remove characters o the right, for example `L[i].rstrip('\n')`

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry that I use most of the time numpy. So a solution can be:

```
li = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
L = np.array(li)

a1 = np.char.array([L[0], L[2]])
a2 = np.char.array([L[1], L[3]])

a1 + a2

chararray(['ab', 'cd'], dtype='<U2')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also `starmap` zipped lists to the operator `concat`:

```
from operator import concat
from itertools import starmap

l = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

z = zip(l[::2], l[1::2])

list(starmap(concat, z))
# ['ab', 'cd']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could slice your list into the even elements and odd elements.

Let's say your list is called `l`

Even elements  - `l[::2]`

Odd elements - `l[1::2]`

Then you could use a list comprehension to concatenate them after zipping. So:

`[x + y for x, y in zip(l[::2], l[1::2])]`